# Is there a clean way to splice some args to an existing Lisp macro?

Tags: use-package, elisp-macros

I have the following non-working elisp code:

```
(use-package eglot
         ;; For debug/testing, load local copy of eglot if it exists
         ,@(if (file-directory-p (concat user-emacs-directory "/eglot"))
               '(:load-path "eglot/")
             '(:quelpa ((eglot :fetcher github :repo "joaotavora/eglot"))))
         :commands eglot
         :hook ((vue-mode . eglot-ensure)
                (typescript-mode . eglot-ensure)
                (javascript-mode . eglot-ensure))
         :config
         (add-to-list 'company-backends  'company-capf))
```

You can see what I'm after -- if `~/.emacs.d/eglot` exists, use the package from my local dir. Otherwise use quelpa to fetch it from its repo. I'm doing this because I'm working on some fixes. The idea is to use `,@` to interpolate items into the arg list.

But of course you can't use `,@` outside of a backquoted list. So I know I could pull all the args out and use `(apply 'use-package eglot-args)` but I'm wondering if there's a clever Elisp syntax to interpolate a list into an arg list dynamically like this.

Comment: I don't see any good way to do this.  You can't `(apply 'use-package eglot-args)` because `use-package` is a macro ([see `apply` docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html)).  I would just put the conditional to either augment `load-path` or call `quelpa` within `:init` (or maybe `:preface`).

Comment: Maybe you can use the `:if` keyword of `use-package` to accomplish what you're after?

Comment: @dsedivec, good point re: macros. Sigh. Adding stuff to `:init` would work, that's a good idea. @Tyler: `:if` would work but I'd have to duplicate the whole thing, prefer not to do that.

Comment: Write your own Lisp macro that produces the `use-package` code you want. Pass it any args you want, and have it test anything you want.

Comment: Ha @Drew, clever! In any case, I ended up switching from `package.el` to `straight.el` which can just handle my case straight-up (pun intended).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have already a [solution for your special use-case (switching from package.el to straight.el) that has nothing to do with macro-expansion](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53484/is-there-a-clean-way-to-splice-some-args-to-an-existing-lisp-macro#comment83481_53484) I will answer your general question
*Is there a clean way to splice some args to an existing Lisp macro?*.

Evaluation of a non-compiled macro form involves both macro expansion and evaluation of the resulting code.
So you should just use `eval` on the backquoted macro form where you splice in the args you like as usual.
Since the arg of `eval` is evaluated before the `eval` the parameters are spliced in before macro expansion of `m`.

I demonstrate that in the following with a simple macro `m`. For each top-level Elisp form the evaluation result is given in the comment following it.

```el
(defmacro m (&rest arglist)
  `(quote (arglist: ,@arglist)))
;; m

(setq splice-in nil)
;; nil

(eval `(m ,@(when splice-in (list :myarg 1))))
;; (arglist:)

(setq splice-in t)
;; t

(eval `(m ,@(when splice-in (list :myarg 1))))
;; (arglist: :myarg 1)
```

If you use that construct in your init files it is no problem that the macro call is not byte-compiled since init files should not be byte-compiled anyway.

Citation of the [Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html):

> Byte-compiling your init file is not recommended (see [Byte Compilation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Byte-Compilation.html#Byte-Compilation)). It generally does not speed up startup very much, and often leads to problems when you forget to recompile the file.

Otherwise you can use the solution proposed by Drew [in one of his comments](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53484/is-there-a-clean-way-to-splice-some-args-to-an-existing-lisp-macro/53490#comment83474_53484). Maybe, he transforms it into an alternative answer.